# Calculate the confidence interval of $u_x-u_y$

Tags: statistics, chemistry

> Chemically it is established that the percentage of iron in five samples of ore extracted in a certain mine has an average of $22.3\%$ and a standard deviation of $1.8\%$. In six samples of ore extracted from another mine the average content was $20\%$ and the standard deviation of $1.3\%$. It is estimated that the variances of the percentages are the same.
>
> Establish the limits of a $95\%$ confidence interval, for the difference in mean iron content between the minerals extracted from the two different mines. Interpreting the results.

#### My attempt

We know the variance of the percentages are the same, and

\begin{align}
n_x &= 5 & \bar{x} &= 22.3\% & s_x &= 1.8\% \\
n_y &= 6 & \bar{y} &= 20\%   & s_y &= 1.3\%
\end{align}

As we want a $95\%$ confidence interval, then

$$\text{let}\quad 1-\alpha=0.95 \quad\to\quad \alpha=0.05 \quad\implies\quad \frac{\alpha}{2}=0.025$$

The interval of confidence have the form:

$$I=(p_1,p_2),$$

where

\begin{align}
p_1&=\bar{x}-\bar{y}-t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(n_x+n_y-2)\sqrt{\frac{n_x+n_y}{n_x\times n_y}\frac{n_xs^2_x+n_ys^2_y}{n_x+n_y-2}} \\
p_2&=\bar{x}-\bar{y}+t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(n_x+n_y-2)\sqrt{\frac{n_x+n_y}{n_x\times n_y}\frac{n_xs^2_x+n_ys^2_y}{n_x+n_y-2}}
\end{align}

I know

$$t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(n_x+n_y-2)=t_{0.025}(9)=2.2622,$$

but I'm stuck when I'm trying to calculate $\bar{x},\bar{y},\ldots$ etc. Can someone help me?